# Фокус формы после SplashScreen

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день, решил добавить в проект SplashScreen в виде формы, вот запуск

```
static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            LoadSplashScreen = new Thread(() => Application.Run(new LoadProgram.MainSplashScreen()));
            LoadSplashScreen.Start();
            //Thread.Sleep(45000);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
```

когда в MainForm происходит событие MainForm_Shown и отработки методов в MainSplashScreen, поток уничтожаю

```
Program.LoadSplashScreen.Abort();
```

но вот в exe файле, в отличии от visualstudio, основная форма скрывается за другими окнами, а

```
Application.OpenForms["MainForm"].Show();
Application.OpenForms["MainForm"].Focus();
```

не работает.
Как сделать чтобы она после запуска стала первичной перед приложениями, как и должно быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простое решение....

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => Application.OpenForms["MainForm"].Activate()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Для начала, не надо убивать поток, показывающий заставку - вместо этого просто закройте эту самую заставку. Поток умрет сам.

Comment: но тогда придется создавать условие ожидания загрузки основной формы и после чего уничтожать форму, а это сложней(ресурсозатратний) и вполне возможно произойдет наложение форм(что не красиво), я в интернете не смог найти SplashScreen с формами, может где то есть

Comment: В чем вы видите лишние затраты? В записи `SplashScreenForm.Close()` вместо `LoadSplashScreen.Abort()`?

Comment: попробовал самостоятельное закрытие, но фокус на основную форму все равно не возвращается , хотя в самой студии все работает при любом варианте